# Zustand in Combination with Suspense breaks Nextjs app

Tags: next.js, zustand

When initiating a store with zustand in a nextjs app and having an (unrelated) suspense block, the app crashes.

Here is a minimal reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-shape-br1uqs?file=/pages/index.js

When removing the suspense block, everything works as expected.

I don't see how they are connected. Does anyone have a workaround?